# MS Word 2013-Can't save anything

Tags: freeze, microsoft-word-2013

Something is deeply screwed with my word processor.  Anytime I try to save something my computer goes into an endless loop and never comes back.  and the file is opening as a read only.  I was getting around that for a bit by"saving as" a new file, but now I can't save anything.

Not sure what to do!  Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Try repairing your copy of MS Office, it worked for me. Go to Control Panel > Programs and Features. Click on Office 2013 and click "Change" on menu bar at top of screen

Comment: Thanks Dave. Actually my office machine does not have the rights to do those changes, hence I was trying to answer from memory